# Linking Haskell to a wrapped C++ library

Tags: c++, c, haskell

I try to create a Haskell binding for Xapian. But when GHC tries to link the binding it fails with some linking issues.

Here's a part of the header file:

```
// file: cbits/libhsxapian.h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

Xapian::Document* xapian_document_C0();
void xapian_document_D0(Xapian::Document* doc);

Xapian::SimpleStopper* xapian_simplestopper_C0();
void xapian_simplestopper_D0(Xapian::SimpleStopper* stopper);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

And the corresponding source file:

```
// file: cbits/libhsxapian.cpp

#include <xapian.h>
#include "hsxapian.h"

Xapian::Document* xapian_document_C0() {
    return new Xapian::Document();
}

void xapian_document_D0(Xapian::Document* doc) {
    delete doc;
}

Xapian::SimpleStopper* xapian_simplestopper_C0() {
    return new Xapian::SimpleStopper();
}

void xapian_simplestopper_D0(Xapian::SimpleStopper* stopper) {
    delete stopper;
}
```

And the Haskell source file containing the FFI code:

```
-- file: src/Bindings/Xapian.hs

{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Bindings.Xapian where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C

type DocumentPtr = Ptr ()

foreign import ccall "hsxapian.h xapian_document_C0"
    xapian_document_C0 :: IO DocumentPtr

foreign import ccall "hsxapian.h &xapian_document_D0"
    xapian_document_D0 :: FunPtr (DocumentPtr -> IO ())

type StopperPtr = Ptr ()

foreign import ccall "hsxapian.h xapian_simplestopper_C0"
    xapian_simplestopper_C0 :: IO StopperPtr

foreign import ccall "hsxapian.h &xapian_simplestopper_D0"
    xapian_simplestopper_D0 :: FunPtr (StopperPtr -> IO ())
```

Among other options the cabal file contains:

```
include-dirs:
    cbits
cxx-sources:
     cbits/hsxapian.cpp
extra-libraries:
     stdc++
```

When I try to compile that package I get the following error message:

```
<command line>: /home/user/hsxapian/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.0.1.0/build/libHShsxapian-0.1.0.0-6mEQUi65qY9HKkEuYL7SJz-ghc8.8.3.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN6Xapian13SimpleStopperE
```

Apparently GHC is unable to link the executable contained in the package with the library.
However, using `nm` I can verify the symbol is present in `libxapian`:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/libxapian.so | grep _ZTVN6Xapian13SimpleStopperE
0000000000226cf0 V _ZTVN6Xapian13SimpleStopperE
$ nm -D -C /usr/lib/libxapian.so | grep 0000000000226cf0
0000000000226cf0 V vtable for Xapian::SimpleStopper
```

Interestingly, if I remove `xapian_simplestopper_C0` from the header, C++ and Haskell source everything compiles and gets linked as expected. And if I add `xapian_document_C0` again it still compiles and gets linked as well.

So my questions are:

1. **Why does GHC choke on `SimpleStopper` but not on `Document`?**

   [SimpleStopper](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1SimpleStopper.html) seems to be an ordinary C++ class like [Document](https://xapian.org/docs/apidoc/html/classXapian_1_1Document.html).
2. **Why does the second run succeed?**

   I expected it to fail in the linking phase with the exact same error message. Doesn't the executable get linked again or is GHC somehow able to find the missing symbol?
3. **How do I debug such a linking issue?**

   I didn't find any valuable resource on this online. Are there some flags I missed in the GHC user guide? Besides that, I'm aware of the following:

   - https://www.codinginfinity.me/posts/haskell-and-cpp/
   - http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2016/12/06/generate-c-interface-from-c-source-code-using-clang-libtooling/
   - [CPlusPlus from Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/CPlusPlus_from_Haskell) and [Cxx foreign function interface](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cxx_foreign_function_interface) at the Haskell Wiki

Comment: Even if I don't know much about the FFI, this sound really weird to me. If I understand correctly, you got a link error, then you removed a line and it worked, then you re-added the same line, reverting to the previous source, and it worked again. If the build process is that inconsistent I'd guess the dependencies are not properly handled.